# Binding annotation @InjectView without @Inject declared warning

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, roboguice

I got this warning in my project. I'm learning to use IntelliJ IDEA as my IDE.

Here's the code with warnings:

```
@InjectView(R.id.button)
private Button loginBtn;
```

The full messages are as follows:

> Binding annotation `@InjectView(R.id.button)` without `@Inject` declared less... (Ctrl+F1)
>
> This inspection reports binding annotations on fields or parameters without a matching @Inject annotation.
>
> Such annotations will be ignored by Guice. 
>       Powered by GuiceyIDEA

I can't understand what it want me to do.

I add a `@Inject` annotation on the field and the warning did disappear, but the app doesn't work.

So how should I do to fix the warning?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

we are using android studio since few months but I had never faced this type of issue..

But please make sure if you are using butterknife in android activity then use

```
@InjectView(R.id.button)
private Button loginBtn;
```

do not forgot to call this

```
ButterKnife.inject(this);
```

after **setContentView** in Activity class

Hope it helps you !!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using RoboGuice as the DI framework. And it works fine on Eclipse.